# iOS:When use the parameter of `isProxy`?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In `objective-c`, I often see the parameter `isProxy`,such as `[UIApplication sharedApplication].isProxy`, I want to know how, and when to use this parameter?

Comment: Please check this link : https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418528-isproxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This method is necessary because sending isKindOfClass: or isMemberOfClass: to an NSProxy object will test the object the proxy stands in for, not the proxy itself. Use this method to test if the receiver is a proxy (or a member of some other root class).

[isProxy Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCIEJEC)

Other Sources

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838312/nsstringfromclass-and-iskindofclass-on-nsdistantobject-class)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126476/ismemberofclass-vs-comparing-classes-with)